# I want to use swift class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to use my swift class in an objective-c file and need to modify string values.

Also, want to use media class in `ObjPost`

I try to import both classes in ProjectName-Swift.h file

```
@class ObjPost;
@class ObjMedia;
```

---

below is my swift class

```
@objc class ObjPost:NSObject, Codable {

/// Post ID
var id:Int

///
var contentAvailable : Bool

/// Post User ID
var userId : Int

/// Post user name
var userName : String

/// Profile Image (Display Picture)
var userProfileImage: String

var subTitle : String
var postedSince : String
var isPin : Bool
var location : String
var lat : String
var long: String

var albumName:String
var isLiked: Bool
var isDisliked : Bool
var likes : Int
var dislikes: Int
var shares: Int
var comments:Int
//var postDescription: String?
var postDescription: String?
//    var objPostDescription: String
var albumId: Int
var privacy: Int
var isEditable: Bool
var media:[ObjMedia]
}
```

---

```
@objc class ObjMedia:NSObject, Codable {
/// Media ID
var id: Int

/// 1==Image, 2==Video
var type: Int // 1 = Image, 2=Video
var url: String
var description: String?
var thumb: String
var isLiked: Bool
var isDisliked:Bool

/// like counter
var likes:Int

/// dislike counter
var dislikes: Int

/// share counter
var shares: Int

/// comment counter
var comments: Int
var isEditable:Bool
var isPin: Bool
var isCoverMedia: Bool
}
```

> I am using this class but I can't get variable in an objective-c file.

When I get userName from ObjPost the error will occur
`Property 'userName' cannot be found in forward class object 'ObjPost'`

[image].

Comment: in the objective c file where you want to use that swift class did you write "# import ProjectName-Swift.h" ? You don't need to import swift classes directly.

Comment: Yes, I import ProjectName-Swift.h file in my objective-c file I create `ObjPost` in my objective-c file but when I try to assign values in userName the error will occur as per above screenshot.

Comment: Did you import that in .m file?

Comment: I need to create property of ObjPost class so I import in .h file.  and this is work file. Not any error for create property, but when I try to access other variable from ObjPost then error will show as per above question.

Comment: ProjectName-Swift.h should be imported in .m file

Comment: as per your suggetion I import ProjectName-Swif.h file in .m file but not working :(

Answer (score 0):

declare variable using @objc like below code and then try:

```
@objc var userName : String
```

the above one is not working you said, so I tried to make a full code. I have created a file Country.swift in the project there I have written below code:

```
    @objc class CountrySwift: NSObject {
     var name: String = ""
     var ranking: String = ""
     }
```

then in the something.m file I write:

```
#import "TargetName-Swift.h"
```

If TargetName contains space, replace the space with '_'
Then  use the class like :

```
 CountrySwift *country = [[CountrySwift alloc] init];
 country.name = @"Bangladesh";
```

This works without any error.

If you need this swift class into .h file also (don't import TargetName-Swift.h in .h file ) then try like below code:

```
@class CountrySwift;

@interface ObjectiveCClass : NSObject

-(CountrySwift* ) countryObject;

@end
```

Comment: I added full process to the answer which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> I try to import both classes in ProjectName-Swift.h file
>
> ```
> @class ObjPost;
> @class ObjMedia;
> ```

You call those imports but they are not. They are just forward declarations. They tell the compiler nothing about these classes.

There is a shared Objective-C header. Look in your app target's build settings under "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" to find out what its name is. It will be something like *MyApp-Swift.h*. You need to import at file at the top of all implementation files that need it (*.m* files, not *.h* files):

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h" // except you need to get the name right
```

Comment: If I import in .m file then How should I send reference from swift file to objective-c file without import in .h file ?

Comment: Swift has a different import file. Please stick to the question you asked. You do what I said, the error goes away, done.